# Can't Save IDs from other tables into current table in database upon creation of an object Rails, Postgresql

Tags: database, ruby-on-rails-3, postgresql

I'm having problems getting multiple ids to save properly into my database. 
I have a listing that has two parameters: a listing id and a price.

I've tried changing the controller to accept the current_user, and no luck there.
I've tried changing the model, and I've also tried manually creating a listing while giving it a user_id and book_id (checking that it is, indeed, giving the correct book and user ids). In the manual listing, I've also tried to make variable names without the @ symbols, and though there are no errors, I'm still unable to store the values in the database

My listing model:

```
class Listing < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :user
  belongs_to :book
  has_one :order
  belongs_to :user, class_name: 'Listing'
  attr_accessible :listing_id, :price
end
```

My user model:

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :books
  has_many :listings
  belongs_to :creator, class_name: 'User'
end
```

My book model:

```
class Book < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_one :status
  has_one :listing
  belongs_to :user

  attr_accessible :condition, :isbn, :location, :title, :weight, :comment, :description, :price

  validates :isbn, :isbn_format => true
end
```

The create function in my listings controller

```
def create
    @listing = Listing.new(params[:listing])
    @listing.user_id = current_user_id

    respond_to do |format|
      if @listing.save
        format.html { redirect_to @listing, notice: 'Listing was successfully created.' }
        format.json { render json: @listing, status: :created, location: @listing }
      else
        format.html { render action: "new" }
        format.json { render json: @listing.errors, status: :unprocessable_entity }
      end
    end
end
```

How I've tried to manually create the user_id and book_id columns:

```
<b><%= "Returned: "+doc.css("Ack").text %> </b>           #returns if listing was a failure or success
<b><%= "Listing ID: "+doc.css("ItemID").text %></b>       #returns the listing itemID
<% @book = Book.find_by_id(params[:book_id_num]) %><br /> #passed from a previous page
<% @user = User.find_by_id(current_user.id) %>        
<%= @book.id %>                       #successfully displays the correct book id on the web page
<%= @user.id %>                       #successfully displays the id of the current_user
<% Listing.create(:listing_id => doc.css("ItemID").text, :price => price, :book_id => @book.id, :user_id => @user.id)%>
```

But doing it this way will only create a listing with a listing_id and a price.

I've been stuck for a while, and am unsure of how to proceed. I'm also fairly unfamiliar with how a database might function. Can anyone help me out?

Comment: I don't get it, what's going wrong? Does `@listing.user_id = current_user_id; @listing.save` not work?

Comment: No, that does not work in my controller. That's why I'm scratching my head in confusion. I don't understand why at least the user_id wouldn't save in the database

Comment: What does `@listing.save` return? What is `current_user_id`? Why do you have two `belongs_to :user` in `Listing`?

Comment: I forgot to delete the second belongs_to :user. I had tried that as a recommendation from another answer. I'm not sure where I'd see where `@listing.save` would return. All I can think is to check the database when a listing is created, and that only has the `listing_ID` and `price` value stored. current_user_id has been fixed in my controller to match my attempt in the manual attempt. It is now `@listing.user_id = User.find_by_id(current_user.id).id`

Comment: So you're setting `@listing.user_id` to a valid non-`nil` value, `@listing.save` returns `true`, but there is no `listings.user_id` in the database?

Comment: That is correct. Any ideas as to where I might be going about this incorrectly?

Comment: I don't see anything obviously wrong (other than the double `belongs_to`). Can you create them properly in the console?

Comment: I figured out what I was doing wrong. Thank you for the tip with the console. I hadn't thought to check that. I'll post what I did below

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured out the answer to my problem.

Using the rails console, it told me that it was unable to edit certain attributes in the creation of a listing.

I'm not sure if it's the rails way to do things, but if I allow the user_id and book_id to be accessible attributes, I am able to store the listing with the correct ids in the database. So my listing model looks as follows:

```
class Listing < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :user
  belongs_to :book
  has_one :order
  belongs_to :user, class_name: 'Listing'
  attr_accessible :listing_id, :price, :user_id, :book_id
end
```

I can edit these values in the table appropriately when I create a listing. 
Thanks to mu is too short for giving me the tip to check the creation of a listing in the rails console. I was not aware that it could be used in such a useful way.